# array.length returns undefined if the last element is undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following code:

```
function lastElement(array) {
  if (array.length > 0)
    return array[array.length - 1];
  else
    return undefined;
}

alert(lastElement([ undefined,1, 2]));
```

Which returns 2 since it doesn't counts the undefined element & that's perfectly fine.Now if i swap the last element in the array with the undefined:

```
function lastElement(array) {
  if (array.length > 0)
    return array[array.length - 1];
  else
    return undefined;
}

alert(lastElement([ 1, 2,undefined]));
```

**It returns undefined!!** Why is it so? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the last element in the array is `undefined`.

The array has 3 elements `1`, `2` and `undefined` where undefined has the index 2 and the array has a length of 3.

Thus when `array[array.length - 1]` is returned it is `undefined`

Comment: i did a huge mistake not properly watching the function. Thanks & so stupid of me asking this. +1 and will accept your answer in a minute

Answer (score 2):

Because "undefined" is treated as an element of an array !!

Answer (score 1):

You are asking it for the last element - the last element is undefined - therefore you are getting back exactly what you asked for.

In the first case it is not ignoring the undefined array element, it is counting it but you are not outputting its value. If you had an array where every value was undefined, every index would return undefined through that function.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't says `array.length` is `undefined` .. As you are returning last element of the array , it says `undefined`

```
function lastElement(array) {
  if (array.length > 0)
    return array[array.length - 1];
  else
    return undefined;
}

alert(lastElement([ 1, 2,undefined]));
```

Here `array.length = 3` and `array[array.length - 1] = undefined`