# Javascript: get length returns undefined

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

Below are the links I gone through:
**1.** [Javascript : array.length returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21552402/javascript-array-length-returns-undefined)
**2.** [Javascript Array.length returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41876248/javascript-array-length-returns-0)
**3.** [array.length returns undefined if the last element is undefined in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475097/array-length-returns-undefined-if-the-last-element-is-undefined-in-javascript)

**Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var freelancer = <?php echo json_encode($results); ?>;

    console.log(freelancer);  // freelancers: Array(19)
    console.log(freelancer.length); // undefined
    console.log(Object.keys(freelancer).length);  // 1
</script>
```

**Console Log:**
[image]

Now how can I get the exact length of the array?

Comment: `freelancer.freelancers`

Answer (score 2):

```
var freelancer = <?php echo json_encode($results); ?>;
```

is an object with a property freelancers in it.

Use

```
freelancer.freelancers.length
```

to access the array.